# Delete first n lines in file (.zip file with many "strange" symbols)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, zip, edit

This powershell code delete first 4 lines in file

```
(gc "old.zip" | select -Skip 4) | sc "new.zip"
```

But `old.zip` file has **Unix (LF)** line endings

And this code also converts file line endings to **Windows (CR LF)**

> How to delete first 4 lines without converting ?

Because of the presence of many "strange" symbols in **.zip**, other ways to remove the first n lines in a .zip file do not work. For example, `more than +4 "old.zip"> "new.zip"` in `cmd` does not work, etc.

Through powershell something like it is removed but also not without problems.

> Do you know other ways to remove the first n lines in a **.zip** file ?

Comment: What makes you think you want to remove "lines" from a zip file? Is it not an actual compressed archive file?

Comment: Yes, it is copy file.txt + archive.zip result.zip

Comment: Pray tell us, what exactly you are trying to do? This sounds quite weird a scenario, thus the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is suspected.

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this?

```
$PathZipFile="c:\temp\File_1.zip"
$NewPathZipFile="c:\temp\NewFile_1.zip"

#create temporary directory name
$TemporyDir=[System.IO.Path]::Combine("c:\temp", [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())

#extract archive into temporary directory
Expand-Archive "c:\temp\File_1.zip" -DestinationPath $TemporyDir

#loop file for remove 4 first lines for every files and compress in new archive
Get-ChildItem $TemporyDir -file | %{

    (Get-Content $_.FullName | select -Skip 4) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName;
    Compress-Archive $_.FullName $NewPathZipFile -Update

}

Remove-Item  $TemporyDir -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: what is your powershell version?

Answer (score -1):

PowerShell:

```
(gc "old.txt" | select -Skip 4 | Out-String) -replace "`r`n", "`n" | Out-File "new.txt"
```

C#:

```
File.WriteAllText("new.txt", string.Join("\n", File.ReadLines("old.txt").Skip(4)));
```